# How to insert data from CSV using sqlcmd?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcmd

I can convert data database to `.csv` using `sqlcmd` syntax

```
sqlcmd -S ipdb -U sa -P "passwordsa" -d dbname -Q "select * from tabelname" -o "direktori/file.csv" -s"," -W -w 700
```

but how can I insert data from my `.csv` to table using `sqlcmd` syntax?

Comment: There's a convoluted way to do it in `SQLCMD`. Instead I suggest that you use `BCP.EXE` to import. In fact I suggest you also export with `BCP.EXE` using native format

Comment: ***Suggestion***: Instead ```sqlcmd``` you can use ```BULK INSERT``` to import bulk data into SQL-Server, for more details please check Microsoft article [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
BULK INSERT Sales.Orders
FROM '\\SystemX\DiskZ\Sales\data\orders.csv'
WITH ( FORMAT='CSV');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally this problem solve.
I Use Bulk Copy Data (BCP) syntax on Ubuntu 20.04

```
bcp Tablename in ~/filename.txt -S localhost -U sa -P <your_password> -d Databasename -c -t  ','
```

Comment: I suggest you use `-N` format to export and import to ensure there is none of the usual issues with delimited files. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-unicode-native-format-to-import-or-export-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: When using the SQL Server 2022 Linux Docker image, the `bcp` tool is inside `/opt/mssql-tools/bin/` (just like `sqlcmd`), which is not in `$PATH`, for some reason.